# modx revo getResources фильтрация типа contains

Tags: modx, revo

Использую `getResources`, там есть фильтрация по `TV`. И она работает как лайк `"tvname==%val%"` или просто `"tvname==val"`, еще возможны всякие вариации. У меня есть множественное тв поле со значениями `a==1||b==2||c==3||d==4||e=11`.

Если я в админке выбираю `"a"` и `"b"`, то они в базе хранятся как `"1,2"`.
И еще, например, есть другой документ с категориями `"e"` и `"d"` -> в базе как `"11,4"`.

Так вот когда я хочу отфильтровать по категории по `"a"`, то и с `"e"(11)` тоже выводит.

Использую `"tvname==%value%"`. Подскажите, как этого избежать, и чтобы было как `contains`.

Comment: Замечание - это выводятся эти значения как `"1,2"` а в базе они хранятся как `"1||2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно сложная задачка и решается только через хитрый запрос напрямую через xpdo. getResources естественно так не умеет. Вот как это делается через pdoResources:

```
[[pdoResources?
    &parents=`0`
    &depth=`1`
    &tpl=`@CODE: <div>[[+pagetitle]] - [[+tv.test]]</div>`
    &includeTVs=`test`
    &where=`{
        "`TVtest`.`value`:RLIKE": "^1\\|\\|.*",
        "OR:`TVtest`.`value`:LIKE": "%||1||%",
        "OR:`TVtest`.`value`:RLIKE": ".*\\|\\|1$",
        "OR:`TVtest`.`value`:=": "1"
    }`
]]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Странно, что нет какого-то более простого способа решения этой задачи. Потому, что очень часто нужно сделать что-то подобное. В EVO всё решалось на много проще.

Comment: @АлександрВасильев в данном случае Вам нужно написать автору о Ваших предположениях, а не править ответ.

Comment: проверьте пожалуйста не является ли ошибкой  `TVtest`? не стоит ли заменить `TVtest` на `test`, чтобы код работал правильно как считает автор вопроса ?

Comment: Заменять ни в коем случае не стоит - таковы правила подключения тв полей в запросе where в `pdoResources` - код который я написал протестирован мной и доказал свою работоспособность.

Comment: @Vasis С версии 1.4.0 вы можете указать просто:
`&includeTVs=\`test\`
&where=\`{
 "test:!=":"0"
}\``и замена в запросе будет произведена автоматически. https://bezumkin.ru/sections/components/1462/

Comment: Можете, но в данном конкретном случае при автоматической замене запрос может просто-напросто поломаться, поэтому указан полный префикс и кавычки.